# How to find char* in a vector of string

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a `char* t`, that I want to find it in a vector of strings.
For example, the `char *t` points to `"abc"`, and my vector has the same `"abc"` as a `string`.

Comment: Do you know about regex? or the [find functions](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) of `std::string`?

Comment: Do you mean a vector of `char`s?

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::find` - it will implicitly convert the `char*` to a `std::string`.

```
auto foundIterator = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), t);
```

If the element is not in the vector, then `foundIterator` will be equal to `vec.end()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tryed to do it, but for some reason it didnt find the char* in the vector. maybe Im using it wrong?
std::find(v.begin(),v.end(),temp)!=v.end()

Comment: 'if(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), t)!=v.end())'

Comment: @kande Do you want the `char*` to be a part of the string, or to be the whole string?

Comment: @kande: It should be passed as a `std::string` holding the entire contents of the `char *`. See my "answer" for a demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a new answer in itself, just some demo code for what @Luchian posted:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 

    std::vector<std::string> data;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::ostringstream b;
        b << "String " << i;
        data.push_back(b.str());
    }

    auto pos = std::find(data.begin(), data.end(), "String 3");

    std::cout << pos-data.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

At least when I run this, it appears to find the string (it prints out `3`).